# CSS animation loading slowly in Safari

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm having a CSS animation to move the div upwards in my react project. On Safari mobile, it's taking almost >2 mins to load the entire animation.

1st case -- Entire data is loaded from the backend. You can see elements initially.
2nd case -- Then for the next 2 mins, data comes and goes off.
3rd case -- Then everything loads properly and works.

On the Desktop, its works properly and on Chrome mobile it is taking 5 secs to load everything which is fine.

```css
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.gridcontainer {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.outer {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inner {
  animation: move 10s linear infinite;
  rposition: relative;
  height: fit-content;
  
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 2vw;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: fit-content;
}

.grid--1x3 {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.flexcolumn {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">
  <div class='grid grid--1x3'>

    <div class='flexcolumn'>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element A</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element B</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element C</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element D</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element E</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element F</span>

    </div>
    <div class='flexcolumn'>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element A</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element B</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element C</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element D</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element E</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element F</span>

    </div>

    <div class='flexcolumn'>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element A</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element B</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element C</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element D</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element E</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element F</span>

    </div>

  </div>
  <div class='grid grid--1x3'>

    <div class='flexcolumn'>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element A</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element B</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element C</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element D</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element E</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element F</span>

    </div>
    <div class='flexcolumn'>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element A</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element B</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element C</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element D</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element E</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element F</span>

    </div>

    <div class='flexcolumn'>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element A</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element B</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element C</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element D</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element E</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element F</span>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have tested this in Safari. Is CSS animation problematic with Safari? What do you suggest I do as a fallback case to ensure data is loaded at all times?

Comment: What do you mean by "loading"? It should just start in any browser.

Comment: Till CSS animations are loaded, Elements are appearing and go off. After 2 mins, I guess that when everything is loaded, things are working properly.

Comment: Still don't understand, are you waiting for data from servers? An animation by itself doesn't need time to load.

Comment: So I don't have any problem on Chrome, Desktop. So I'm guessing it's not a problem with the Server. 

Only when I am accessing it through Safari Mobile, data comes. and go off. 

After 2 mins, everything loads properly. This can only happen due to CSS loading problem right?

Comment: highly unlikely. this has to be debugged via devtools. if you're on a mac, you can connect mobile safari to your desktop-safari-devtools. can you provide a minimal reproducible example somehow?